# @selector multiple Arguments error with CCCallFunc

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying this stuff but there is Run Time Error in the next method i.e. changeCardsfirst2  I am unable to find what goes wrong. Please suggest me for this error

```
-(void) changeFirst2Cards : (CCSprite *) chgcard0 :(CCSprite *) chgcard1
{
    id a1 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.5f];
    id a2 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(changeCardsfirst2:data:)  ];
    id action = [CCSequence actions:a1,a2,nil];

    [self runAction:action];
}
-(void) changeCardsfirst2 : (id) sender data:(CCSprite *)chgcard1
{
    [chgcard1 runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(145,wSize.height-110)]]; // Error for EXEC_BAD EXCCESS
}
```

Thanks for the Advice in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Your selector does not use the parameters required by [CCCallFunc](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_call_func.html) - it should have no parameters. [CCCallFuncN](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_call_func_n.html) will run a selector with the node as its first argument, and [CCCallFuncND](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_call_func_n_d.html) will run a selector with the node and an arbitrary void* pointer as its second argument.

You should use CCCallFuncN:

```
id a2 = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
                             selector:@selector(changeCardsfirst2:)];
```

And change the selector accordingly to work with the node:

```
-(void) changeCardsfirst2:(CCNode*)chgcard1
{
    id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f 
                                  position:ccp(145,wSize.height-110)];
    [chgcard1 runAction:move];
}
```

Comment: I need to change the position of the Sprite but it changes the whole Scene to the particular position. Can I get the Sprite instead of whole Node?

Answer (score 1):

The only possible reason is that chgcard1 was over-released somewhere earlier.
I've never used Cocos, but if you don't have the source code and using a static lib then just create the category of CCSprite and override the dealloc method (this is temporary just to see when it is called for this object). If you're building using Cocos sources then just create a breakpoint there.

Comment: after the break point it gives an error goes under the changeCardsfirst2 method and stops executing it

Comment: Well of course it crashes. The main purpose is to check the backtrace and see why dealloc is called.